# multiple checkbox validation in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
libraryApp.directive("checkboxGroup", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    
                // Determine initial checked boxes
                if (scope.groupArray.indexOf(scope.item.id) !== -1) {
                    elem[0].checked = true;
                }

                // Update array on click
                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    var index = scope.groupArray.indexOf(scope.item.id);
                    // Add if checked
                    if (elem[0].checked) {
                        if (index === -1) scope.groupArray.push(scope.item.id);
                    }
                    // Remove if unchecked
                    else {
                        if (index !== -1) scope.groupArray.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    // Sort and update DOM display
                    scope.$apply(scope.groupArray.sort(function(a, b) {
                        return a - b
                    }));
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

```css
angular js and bootstrap
```

```html
<form class="userForm" name="userForm" novalidate ng-init="">
 <notifications></notifications>
 <section>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-11"> 
          <div class="form-group" style="display: flex;" ng-class="{ 'has-error' :(userForm.status.$dirty && userForm.status.$error.required) alert(ram)}" >
    <label class="assetDropdownLabel col-md-2" for="manufacturer">Permission<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    
                <div ng-repeat="item in list"  id="status" name="status" ng-model="status" required ng-required="true" >
    
     <label style="margin-right:12px"><input type="checkbox" style="display:inline;  width: 18px;margin:0px" checkbox-group required  />{{item.value}}</label>
     
    </div>    
    <div ng-show="userForm.status.$dirty && userForm.status.$error.required" class="help-block col-md-offset-2">Required field</div>
  
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </section>

 <div class="btnContainer addUserBtn" >
  <button type="button" ng-click="finalValidation()" class="pull-right primarybutton btn_small addmargintopbottom" alt="{{buttonTitle}}" ng-disabled="userForm.$error.pattern">{{buttonTitle}}</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

I want to check validation for checkbox for required; atleast one checkbox needs to be selected then there will be no message or ng-class added in noticification. If no checkbox selected then on finalvalidation() or ng-class should be added

Comment: Did you manage to do this ?